# Python assert with paranthesis allows for only part of the condition to be written within them

Tags: python, assert, assertion

Could someone please explain me why this absolutely weird syntax works in Python (I tested in Python 3.7)? Functionally, it seems perfectly equivalent to the logically corect `assert(5+1 == 6)`, but I have no idea why this would be valid syntax.

```
assert(5) + 1 == 6
```

Comment: `assert` doesn't require parentheses at all.  You're always free to put parentheses around sub-expressions - *anywhere* you could have written `5 + 1`, `(5) + 1` means exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assert` is not a function; it's a statement.

In both cases, your parentheses are part of the expression following the keyword `assert`. The expressions `(5) + 1 == 6`, `(5+1 == 6)`, and `5 + 1 == 6` are equivalent, with the parentheses in the first two cases being unnecessary.

You can see the parser treats them identically:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse("assert(5) + 1 == 6"))
'Module(body=[Assert(test=Compare(left=BinOp(left=Num(n=5), op=Add(), right=Num(n=1)), ops=[Eq()], comparators=[Num(n=6)]), msg=None)])'
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse("assert(5 + 1 == 6)"))
'Module(body=[Assert(test=Compare(left=BinOp(left=Num(n=5), op=Add(), right=Num(n=1)), ops=[Eq()], comparators=[Num(n=6)]), msg=None)])'
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse("assert 5 + 1 == 6"))
'Module(body=[Assert(test=Compare(left=BinOp(left=Num(n=5), op=Add(), right=Num(n=1)), ops=[Eq()], comparators=[Num(n=6)]), msg=None)])'
```

or letting Python compare the strings for you,

```
>>> exprs = ["assert(5) + 1 == 6", "assert(5 + 1 ==  6)", "assert 5 + 1 == 6"]
>>> len(set(ast.dump(ast.parse(x)) for x in exprs))
1
```

---

More formally, the assert statement consists of the `assert` keyword followed by one or two additional expressions.

```
assert_stmt: 'assert' test [',' test]
```

The first one is evaluated as a Boolean expression, producing `True` or `False` as the result. The value of the second one, if present, is used to construct the `AssertionError` raised by the statement if the first expression is `False`.

```
>>> assert False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
>>> assert False, 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError: 3
>>> assert True
>>> assert True, 3
```